# Multiprocessing : Pool : Direct iterator OR use of variable to store the iterator

Tags: python, iterator, multiprocessing, pool

Is there are difference between :

```
  with Pool(...) as pool :
      res = pool.imap_unordered(fun, iterator)
      for val in res :
           ........
```

and ..

```
  with Pool(...) as pool :
      for val in pool.imap_unordered(fun, iterator) :
           ........
```

is the second variant faster !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the disassembled code of the two cases:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fun(x):
    pass


def method1(it):
    with Pool() as pool:
        res = pool.imap_unordered(fun, it)
        for val in res:
            pass

def method2(it):
    with Pool() as pool:
        for val in pool.imap_unordered(fun, it):
            pass

import dis
dis.dis(method1)
print()
print('-' * 80)
print()
dis.dis(method2)
```

Prints:

```
  8           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Pool)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 SETUP_WITH              28 (to 34)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (pool)

  9           8 LOAD_FAST                1 (pool)
             10 LOAD_METHOD              1 (imap_unordered)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (fun)
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
             16 CALL_METHOD              2
             18 STORE_FAST               2 (res)

 10          20 LOAD_FAST                2 (res)
             22 GET_ITER
        >>   24 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 30)
             26 STORE_FAST               3 (val)

 11          28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           24
        >>   30 POP_BLOCK
             32 BEGIN_FINALLY
        >>   34 WITH_CLEANUP_START
             36 WITH_CLEANUP_FINISH
             38 END_FINALLY
             40 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             42 RETURN_VALUE

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 14           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Pool)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 SETUP_WITH              24 (to 30)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (pool)

 15           8 LOAD_FAST                1 (pool)
             10 LOAD_METHOD              1 (imap_unordered)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (fun)
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
             16 CALL_METHOD              2
             18 GET_ITER
        >>   20 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 26)
             22 STORE_FAST               2 (val)

 16          24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           20
        >>   26 POP_BLOCK
             28 BEGIN_FINALLY
        >>   30 WITH_CLEANUP_START
             32 WITH_CLEANUP_FINISH
             34 END_FINALLY
             36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

**Results**

It would appear that the `method1` results in executing two more bytecode instructions (at locations 18 and 20) regardless of the length of the iterator or the amount of processing done by `fun` or in processing the results returned by `fun`. In other words, **such a negligible difference for there to be any cause for concern**.

Comment: wow, thanks ... i was confused cause it seem that method1 was first waiting to get the results and then execute the loop i.e. blocking.. i didnt know both cases the processing between the imap and the loop are interleaved/async